# How can I disable a WPF dialogue OK button in response to invalid input determined by a custom ValidationRule class?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, error-handling, binding

I have a simple WPF dialogue allowing the user to enter a name.  We are using a Mvvm approach without any code-behind files.  I need to validate the input and only enable the OK button when the input is valid.  I am currently doing the validation using a custom error template in my view and a custom implementation of the ValidationRule class.

The text box in the dialogue is defined as:

```
    <TextBox Width="250" Height="25" Margin="5"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource customErrorTemplate}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="WitnessName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ValidationRules:NameRule />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

The NameRule is defined as:

```
public class NameRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var isValid = (value as string == null) || Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$");

        return new ValidationResult(isValid, "Name can contain only letters, apostrophes and hyphens.");
    }
}
```

The OK button IsEnabled property is bound to an IsOkEnabled property on the view model, which is only true when the input is valid.

```
<Button Name="OnOkClick" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOkEnabled}">OK</Button>
```

The IsOkEnabled property is updated in response to a change in the WitnessName text by monitoring the WitnessName PropertyChanged event.

```
public string WitnessName
{
    get
    {
        return this.witnessName;
    }

    set
    {
        this.witnessName = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.IsOkEnabled);
    }
}
```

The problem is that with the validation operating in the view the PropertyChanged event isn't being fired on the vew model when invalid input is entered, so the IsOkEnabled property isn't being updated and the OK button remains enabled.

Is there a way of forcing the update on the IsOkEnabled property in response to a even invalid input on my current implementation?

I have looked at both [Karl Shifflet's](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/input-validation-ui-exceptions-model-validation-errors/) and [Josh Smith's](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/) suggestions but neither uses (as far as I can tell) a view error template and I'd like to use one to provide the visual feedback.

**Update: Trying this with a bound ICommand as suggested by Danny**

I have tried this by creating a VM specific to the OK button, which implements ICommand.  The OkButtonViewModel has a property to hold the dialogue VM (set by IoC and unity) and the CanExecute and Execute implementations refer to the relevant properties/methods on this VM.

In OkButtonViewModel:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return this.witnessDialogue.IsValid;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    this.witnessDialogue.OnOkClick();
}
```

How do I bind my button to this VM rather than the dialogueVM?  I can do it if the OkButtonViewModel is a property on the dialogue VM but not when the dependence is this other way around, which it needs to be for the button to be able to use the implementations on the dialogue VM.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the OnClick event handler, instead use a binding to a command.
Register the command in the VM with a CanExecute method that returns Model.IsValid.

If the validation failure is in the binding of the view to the viewmodel,
then the viewmodel can still be valid - since it didn't store the update (due to type mismatch, range check, etc).

In this case consider storing error state in VM, before throwing exception, then clearing error state if same property was successfully set.

Modified code:

---

XAML:
*(Note that the scope of ValidationRules:NameRule instance is in TextBox, other usages will receive another instance with different field values)*

```
<TextBox Width="250" Height="25" Margin="5"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource customErrorTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="WitnessName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:NameRule x:Name="nameValidator" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

---

Validation rule:

```
public class NameRule : ValidationRule, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public bool HasFailed // set default of field behind to false
   {
      get; // change to support INotifyPropertyChanged
      set; // change to support INotifyPropertyChanged
   }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var isValid = (value as string == null) || Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"^[\p{L} \.'\-]+$");

        HasFailed = !isValid;

        return new ValidationResult(isValid, "Name can contain only letters, apostrophes and hyphens.");
    }
}
```

---

Command:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return this.witnessDialogue.IsValid && !this.witnessDialogue.nameValidator.HasFailed;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    this.witnessDialogue.OnOkClick();
}
```

Comment: Danny, thanks for the response. I think the problem is that the property in the VM is never being set (or attempted to set) because the validation in the view is intervening so I can't handle the error there.

Comment: I have updated my question with my attempt to implement what you have suggested.  Could you tell me where I am going wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question but for those that are lead here by Google like I was...

The best way (that I know of) to do this in WPF with MVVM is to use IDataErrorInfo interface on your view model where the command definition is.  This lets you validate and have the validation info in your view model to work with on your CanExecute implementation.  I found a good thorough description of using this at https://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/ (did not write that, just a useful link I found).

Hope that helps someone!